# Huge left margin in reveal.js

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, reveal.js

I am working to create some slides using reveal.js (from within R markdown if it matters). Compared to other frameworks (like ioslides or slidy) there are HUGE margins to the left of the text, as in the graphic below.

[image: huge margin reveal.js]

I've been trying to edit the css to move the text further to the left but to no avail.

Any ideas?

My css style section is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .reveal p {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .reveal ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .reveal ol {
        display: block;
    }
    Reveal.initialize({ width: 1920, height: 1080, margin: 0.00,  });
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much investigation, I did figure out a solution (at least in Rmarkdown). Specifically, I added the width and height argument under reveal_options in my output header. The settings below look much better for a 16:9 aspect ratio display.

```
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    reveal_options:
      width: 1280
      height: 720
```